# if condition is not working in android onPostExecute Method

Tags: android, json

if i am set the if condition in my code then result are not show..... in logcat and output
data are coming from Json

**This is my Code**

```
 protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject result) {
      String booking_mode   = result.optString("booking_mode").toString();

         Log.d("booking mode", booking_mode+"//T"); // this data are show in logcat

                if(booking_mode.equals("T"))
                {
                    System.out.print("Deepak acharya");
                     Log.d("booking mode", booking_mode+"//T"); // this data are not show in log cat
                  booking_mode_value.setText(  "Total Paid");
                }
    }
```

Comment: What is the output of `Log.d("booking mode", booking_mode+"//T");` ?

Comment: the out is how in logcat as T//T   but i set the condition then result are not show

Comment: I think every thing is fine, try to trim the string booking_mode
booking_mode.trim();

Comment: thankyu Ganesh katikar

Answer (score 1):

Try this . I hope this helps you

```
protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject result) {
  String booking_mode   = result.optString("booking_mode").toString().trim();

     Log.d("booking mode", booking_mode+"//T"); // this data are show in logcat

            if(booking_mode.equalsIgnoreCase("T"))
            {
                System.out.print("Deepak acharya");
                 Log.d("booking mode", booking_mode+"//T"); // this data are not show in log cat
              booking_mode_value.setText("Total Paid");
            }
}
```

Comment: @Deepak : Tell me what is your op of Log.D(); ??